# ¿Como ordenar un array de palabras alfabéticamente y luego por longitud?

Tags: javascript

¿Cómo puedo hacer para que a partir de un texto, se devuelva un listado de las palabras ordenadas alfabéticamente? Después, aparte, que las palabras se ordenen de mayor a menor según su longitud.

```js
var arr =  [ 'La', 'mayor', 'sabiduria', 'que', 'existe', 'es', 'conocerse', 'a', 'uno', 'mismo', 'Galileo', 'Galilei' ];

arr.sort();

document.getElementById("letras").innerHTML = arr;
```

```html
<html>
<body>
    <p>La mayor sabiduría que existe es conocerse a uno mismo. Galileo Galilei</p>
    <h3>Lista Ordenada:</h3>
    <p id="letras"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Bienvenido CarolAlex, deberías pasarte por el [Tour](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para conocer SO. Revisa en el [Centro de Ayuda](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help) los apartados [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) y [Cómo crear un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Deberías añadir información sobre que esperas que haga cada parte de tu código, porque lo intentas así y que otras formas has probado. No estamos aquí para hacer los deberes, sino para ayudar con problemas concretos de programación.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes implementar tu propia función de comparación y usarla con [`sort()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/sort) de los arrays, pasándole una función de comparación.

Ahora mismo tu programa estará ordenando alfabéticamente pero con mayúsculas primero. Para ordenar ignorando mayúsculas y minúsculas [esto es lo más sencillo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9645447/3290971):

```
arr.sort(function (a, b) {
    return a.toLowerCase().localeCompare(b.toLowerCase());
});
```

Para ordenar por longitud de palabras (más largo primero) sería algo así:

```
arr.sort(function(a, b) {
    return b.length - a.length
});
```

La clave es que la función `sort()` devuelva:

- Un número positivo si el primer parámetro es considerado mayor.
- Un número negativo si el primer parámetro es considerado menor.
- 0 si los dos parámetros son iguales.

Algo así es lo que querrás para obtener las dos ordenaciones:

```js
var ordenAlfabetico = [ 'La', 'mayor', 'sabiduria', 'que', 'existe', 'es', 'conocerse', 'a', 'uno', 'mismo', 'Galileo', 'Galilei' ];
var ordenLongitud = ordenAlfabetico.slice(); // Copia el array

// Para ordenar con mayúsculas primero te vale con solo ordenAlfabetico.sort();
ordenAlfabetico.sort(function (a, b) {
    return a.toLowerCase().localeCompare(b.toLowerCase());
});

ordenLongitud.sort(function(a, b) {
    return a.length - b.length
});


document.getElementById("letras").innerHTML = 'Alfabetico: ' + ordenAlfabetico + '<br>Longitud: ' + ordenLongitud;
```

```html
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Segundo Algoritmo</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p>La mayor sabiduría que existe es conocerse a uno mismo. Galileo Galilei</p>
    <h3>Lista Ordenada:</h3>
        <p id="letras"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: si, lo que tengo que hacer es que se ordenen por separado.

Comment: Entonces necesitas tener dos arrays. `sort()` te va a cambiar el array original.

Comment: @CarolAlex he actualizado mi respuesta.

Answer (score 0):

siendo la variable arrayVar , el array que quieres ordenar

```
var arrayVar = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango"];
```

orden alfabetico

```
arrayVar.sort();
```

orden por tamaño de las palabras

```
arrayVar.sort(function (a, b) {
   return b.length - a.length;
});
```

Espero te sirva de ayuda,

Un saludo.